# Failed to process impala request after drop and create partition

Tags: python-3.x, impala

OS: centos 7.4.1708
   Python: 3.6
   impyla==0.14.0
   thriftpy==0.3.9

I have one use case:

1. Create Table
2. Add partition
3. Insert values
4. Drop partition (to remove old date)
5. Create partition
6. Insert values

on the step 6 I got error `thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')`

Test:

```
class TestExecution:
SQL_LIST = [
    "create schema if not exists test",

    "drop table if exists test.test_table",
    """
    create table test.test_table(
        id                 string not null,
        tran_time          bigint not null,
        primary key (tran_time, id)
    )
    partition by range(tran_time) (partition 0 <= values <= 1262304000) -- till 2010-01-01
    stored as kudu
    """
]
INSERT = "insert into test.test_table (id, tran_time) values('1', 1577836800)"

DROP = "alter table test.test_table drop if exists range partition 1577836800 <= values < 1577923200"
ADD = "alter table test.test_table add if not exists range partition 1577836800 <= values < 1577923200"

@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
    sql_runner.execute_sql_list(cls.SQL_LIST)

def test_remove_old_data(self):

    sql_runner.execute_sql(self.ADD)
    sql_runner.execute_sql(self.INSERT)

    sql_runner.execute_sql(self.DROP)
    sql_runner.execute_sql(self.ADD)

    sql_runner.execute_sql(self.INSERT)
```

Traceback:

```
    hiveserver2.py             946 ERROR    Failed to open transport (tries_left=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 940, in _execute
    return func(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/protocol/binary.py", line 372, in read_message_begin
    self.trans, strict=self.strict_read)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/protocol/binary.py", line 164, in read_message_begin
    sz = unpack_i32(inbuf.read(4))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/__init__.py", line 32, in read
    return readall(self._read, sz)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/__init__.py", line 14, in readall
    chunk = read_fn(sz - have)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/buffered/__init__.py", line 39, in _read
    self._rbuf = BytesIO(self._trans.read(max(sz, self._buf_size)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py", line 125, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
```

Do you have any idea why it fails?